# Codeigniter + whitelabel site + single application + multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, white-labelling

Below is my folder structure for Codeigniter based application.

```
application
  config
    development
      config.php
      database.php
      constants.php
    testing
      config.php
      database.php
      constants.php
```

We want to setup white label in our application so we decided to change the structure having single application and multiple database for white label doing so each new partner will have their data stored in separate database.

Below is the new directory structure.

```
application {folder}
  config {folder}
    development {folder}
      config.php    - Default site config
      database.php  - Default site database  
      constants.php - Default site constants
      whitelabel {folder}
        Site1 {folder}
          config.php
          database.php
          constants.php
        Site2 {folder}
          config.php
          database.php
          constants.php
```

When we implemented this structure, the problem I am facing is with loading the config and database files for each site.

There are two ways I tried.

**First**, autoload the config for white label site from autoload.php for that I have to conditionally load the config file depending upon the HTTP_HOST.

**Second**, I make changes in the "System/Core/Common.php" file or override the function which loads the config files.

Please suggest how I can load configs and database for each whitelabel site.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is a multi tenant architecture.